# Can I read the public SSH key of another user?

Tags: ssh, permissions, openssh

The public component of SSH keys theoretically don't need to be kept private. It was therefore to my surprise that I was unable to read the public key of another user on the system:

```
andreas:~$ cat /home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat: /home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
```

The permissions of the key file allow me to read the `id_rsa.pub` file (`644`), the problem is the `.ssh` directory has the permission `700`.

Is there any system in place for listing the public keys of other users on the system without having to be root or logging in as each user individually?

Comment: There is `ssh-keyscan` for host keys. I wasn't sure if there was something vaguely similar for user keys.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you get a copy of the public key for someone because they *publish* it (whether by sending it to you directly or putting it in some more generally accessible place).

The original copy of the public key is normally in `~/.ssh` due to the convention of storing the private key directly there as the public/private key pair is created.  Aside from convenience, there is no reason that someone has to *keep* their public key there, since they will be using the private key to furnish their credentials.